# SQL : Query to get results by monthly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query below which gives me the Approved and denied counts by Approver.

But I am unable to get the count for each month Approved and denied. I am pulling the data for back 3 months from 10/1/2018 to 12/31/2018).

![query image][1]

This is how I want to be divided by month

![expected result][2]

Here is the query :

Comment: Please avoid using images on SO as it makes it very hard for people to assist you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I pasted the query again !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting the month of your parameter instead of the month of the record, and not grouping by that value. Change line 20:

```
, Month(@BeginDate) 'Month'
```

to

```
, Month(CONVERT(DATE, pr.CreateDateTime))
```

Then add that (Month(CONVERT(DATE, pr.CreateDateTime))) to your GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Hi Russel- This is helpful, But Instead of Month Number. How do I get the Month Name? Thanks

Comment: Gotcha: you can use DATENAME(MONTH(CONVERT(DATE, pr.CreateDateTime))).

Answer (score 0):

Not able to figure out from code image. Assuming that your fetches everything except Month name.
If that is the case then, try this

```
{Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , 0 ) - 1 )}
```